# Is @Autowired taking care of the nested autowiring?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have the following components, in two different files:

```
@Component
public class Chauffeur {
    Car car;

    public Chauffeur(Car car){
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void go(){
        System.out.println("Chauffeur");
        car.drive();
    }
}

@Component
public class Car{  
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Drive car");
    }
}
```

the following configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DriveableConfiguration {
}
```

and the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=DriveableConfiguration.class)
public class DriveableTest {
    @Autowired
    Chauffeur chauffeur;

    @Test
    public void chauffeurTest(){
        chauffeur.go();
    }
}
```

All the classes above are in the same package and the test is passing.

In the test I annotated `chauffer` with @Autowired, which should mean that the Spring container looks after the creation of the instance of Chauffeur without the developer needing to explicitly instantiate it.
Now, the constructor for Chauffer needs an instance of Car, so there is no default constructor for that class. Nonetheless the container creates it, injecting the required instance in the constructor.

Is the @Autowired saying to the container to instantiate the element with whatever (Components, Beans) it can provide, included parameters in the constructor? If so, in what case is it needed to use @Autowired to annotate a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you use `Spring 4.3+`. In such a case `@Autowired` on constructor is optional if you have one non default constructor.

You can check the example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3#implicit-constructor-injection-for-single-constructor-scenarios).

> So as of 4.3, you no longer need to specify an explicit injection annotation in such a single-constructor scenario. This is particularly elegant for classes which otherwise do not carry any container annotations at all, for example when programmatically registered

For versions lower than 4.3 you will an exception will be thrown:

> the container will throw an exception looking for a default
>   constructor, unless you explicitly indicate autowire mode
>   ‘constructor’ in your bean definition setup (e.g. in an XML )